# if any(s in line for s in list): print line ... not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I'm trying to extract only the lines in a file that contain a string within a list, for example MSTRG.2 is in my list, I want to have the line which contains this in my outfile. I've used the code below, but for some reason the lines that are extracted don't necessarily contain a string in the list.

```
id_list = []

for line in gff_compare:
    split_line = line.strip().split('\t')
    class_code = split_line[2]

    if class_code == 'u':
        if split_line[3] not in id_list:
            id_list.append(split_line[3])


for line in feature_counts:
    split_line_2 = line.strip().split('\t')
    string_ids = split_line_2[0]

    if any(s in string_ids for s in id_list):
        outfile.write(line)

outfile.close()
```

`id_list` contains only 1,511 elements whereas `outfile` has over 30,000 lines (contains lines which have a string in the list and lines which don't have a string in the list). Can't work out why it's not only pulling out the lines I want based on strings in the list.

Comment: `any(s in string_ids for s in id_list)` works, in general. If it "does not work" in your case, it is because contents of string_ids and id_list are not what you think they are.

Comment: For this question to be answerable, you need to provide us with some sample data where it gives a different output to what you expect. Out of those 20,000 lines, can you find one line which this code does the wrong thing for?

Comment: an example line that is not what I would expect is " MSTRG.1720 chr1 136842579 136845710 + 5125 2 7 3 1 2 3 5 3 " but id_list.index("MSTRG.1720") returns ValueError: 'MSTRG.1720' is not in list. So although MSTRG.1720 is not in my list the line is still included in my output. string_ids should be the MSTRG.X (where X is various values)

Comment: I've realised that " if any(s in string_ids for s in id_list) " is only picking out expressions that contain  "s", not necessarily an exact match. E.g my original input file has lines containing MSTRG.2, MSTRG.212, and ENSMUSG.212. In my list there will only be MSTRG.2, but my output file contains MSTRG.2 and MSTRG.212 (not ENSMUSG.212). Is there a way for me to look for an exact match? thanks